# Google is disabled

Tags: applications

Google is disabled on my Samsung Galaxy 4.  It was disabled in "Application Manager."  It now does not appear on the "Applications" listing.  How can I re-enable it?

Comment: Isn't there "enable" button in application manager?

Comment: Depending on your device/ROM, disabled apps may show up in different locations. If it's no longer in the "alphabetical order" of your Application Manager's list: please check 1) at the end of the list and 2) whether there's a specific "Disabled" tab.

Comment: Quick question, OP: are you rooted?

Answer (score -1):

Search google app in playstore then enable it from there . easy as cheese

Comment: This way works directly from the device, where the enable button is available. From the web interface, Installing it again seems to re-enable it, too.

Comment: Well mate he can't seem to find where the disabled apps are.. So this way he can simply enable it without headache.  and without reinstalling he is just enabling a installed app.

Comment: There is still some disagreement here. To disable an app requires first the uninstall of any updates back to its pure distributed state, then a disable. If you re-enable, the required updates will be installed, whichever path is taken. It is just more clearly stated in the web interface that some sort of install action will be triggered.

Comment: I agree with u 